# Why doesn't my custom RewriteMap program return the expected results?

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I want to redirect some urls with `id = n` to `id = n + 1000` (where *n* is a variable). After searching on the internet I found out that I can do this using a prg type RewriteMap directive.

However, I ran into some trouble getting it to work. The code I am using to test using a custom RewriteMap is included below.

This is my test.pl file that I'm using as the map program:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
$| = 1; # Turn off buffering
while (<STDIN>) {
    print $_;
}
```

I've defined the RewriteMap in my virtualhost.conf file:

```
RewriteMap prp prg:/var/www/mydomain1.com/test.pl
```

And this is the RewriteRule where I'm using my custom map:

```
RewriteRule ^Pro-id-([0-9]+).html http://mydomain2.um.ac.ir/papers-${prp:$1}.html [L,R=301]
```

What I expect this code (test.pl) to do is to return the same id, but it returns null.
What is the problem?

Comment: Sure, use a language that the guy that can answer your question barely knows why don't you...

Comment: thanks for editing . i was so tried.

Answer (score 0):

The stuff you have is just fine, a rewritelog with rewriteloglevel 5 or higher would probably reveal that some other rewrite or config is getting in the way.

Answer (score 0):

Since I just spent a day banging my head against the same problem. It is very likely you are using the map in a context it which it is not defined.

In my case I was using https in my test url and the minute I switched to using http everything started working. In retrospect this should have been completely obvious given the way I had set up the config files.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have rewrite engine enabled in your httpd configuration (in either server or virtual host context)

> RewriteEngine on